# Why can't I access a variable declared in derived class with the object of base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Good Evening everyone

I have created two classes namely `Shape`, `Rectangle` with `Draw()` method in both the classes, `Rectangle` class  is a derived class from `Shape`. I have declared a public variable  in `Rectangle` called `num` and initialized a value to it.

In the main class I have created an object of type class in following manner.

```
Shape s = new Rectangle();
```

Now when I am trying to access num variable of rectangle class it gives error saying

> “ /Users/apple/Projects/Practice/Practice/Program.cs(33,33): Error
>   CS1061: 'Shape' does not contain a definition for 'num' and no
>   extension method 'num' accepting a first argument of type 'Shape'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) (CS1061) (Practice)”

My Understanding : The statement `new Rectangle();` creates an object of type `Rectangle` in the memory and its reference is stored in object s of type Shape. So the object s should have access to variable `num` defined in rectangle class. Please make me understand this concept why we can’t access `num` variable from Object of type `Shape`.

Pls find the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of code with error]

Comment: The simplest solution is not to define s as a Shape if you want top use it as a rectangle. If you change your assignment to `var s = new Rectangle();` it should work. You cannot access the variable in a sub class from the super class, because that would make no sense. Say I define a class `Animal`, and a class `Dog` that inherits from `Animal`. Would it make sense that all `Animals` can now `Bark();`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. A standard principle of strongly/statically-typed OOP languages is that the compiler restricts you to members that are known _at compile time_ to exist. If your variable is of type `Shape`, then you could assign _any_ `Shape` object to it, such as `Circle`, or `Triangle`, or whatever. If the compiler let you access `num` which is defined only in `Rectangle`, then at run-time, what's the code supposed to do? This is fundamental to statically-typed languages like C#. Compile-time rules prevent you from writing bad code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
Shape s - new Rectangle();
```

to

```
Rectangle s = new Rectangle();
```

`Shape s` has no `num` since it is `Shape` not `Rectangle`

Comment: Or simply `var s = new Rectangle();`.

Comment: `var s =` is really just syntactic sugar for `Rectangle s` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You could access `s.num` in a dynamic language. In a dynamic language, the type tests and tests for availability of members are performed at runtime. The runtime type of `s` is `Rectangle`, i.e. `s` references an object of type `Rectangle`. However, C# is a statically and strongly typed language. I.e. these tests are performed at compile-time. At compile-time, only members available through the static type of `s` are visible. `num` is not a member of the static type `Shape` and is therefore invisible.

The `Shape` object (indeed any class) sees its own members and members of its ancestors, i.e. inherited members, if they are public or protected. It cannot see members of derived classes (here `Rectangle`), since they are not declared in `Shape`, nor are they known at compile time, if the 2 classes are declared in 2 different assemblies.

A base class must contain everything which is common to itself and its descendants.
If you still want to access `Rectangle` stuff from a `Shape` variable, you can cast (assuming VS 2017):

```
if (shape is Rectangle rect) {
    var x = rect.num;
}
```

However, this is often a sign of a bad OO-design. In this case, you could simply override `ToString`

```
public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    private int num = 10;

    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Rectangle num = {num}";
    }
}
```

...

```
Shape shape = new Rectangle();
Console.WriteLine(shape); // Uses ToString() of rectangle.
```

Comment: When the statement Shape s = new Rectangle(); gets compiled dosent an object of type Rectangle gets created in memory and it's reference gets stored in object s and now it acts like a pointer and we should be able to access num. 
Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Since `s` is typed as `Shape`, `num` is not visible through `s`; however, you can access it with casting: `((Rectangle)s).num`. This means, *"I know that the `Shape s` is in reality a `Rectangle`, so treat it as such and access `num`"*. If you are not sure whether `s` is a rectangle, you can write: `var r = s as Rectangle; if (r != null) { Console.WriteLine(r.num); }`, or, with c# 7.0, `if (s is Rectangle r) { Console.WriteLine(r.num); }`

Comment: Thanks Olivier for clarifying my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

A object object of type Shape can access only members defined in Shape class. You have two options:

1. Define `num` in `Shape` class itself and it will be available to `Rectangle` class.
2. Cast object `s` to `Rectangle`  type to be able to use it.

The principle wise, I prefer option#1. One should define properties and methods to be used by both base and sub-class in base class.

Comment: When the statement Shape s = new Rectangle(); gets compiled dosent an object of type Rectangle gets created in memory and it's reference gets stored in object s and now it acts like a pointer and we should be able to access num. 
Please correct me where I am going wrong.